# using regular expression to remove rows from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
         Word      Rating
   0     Bear      1
   1     Yuck      2
   2     Girl      3
   3     Yellow    4
```

How can I use regex in pandas to filter out the rows that have the word that starts with the letter "y" but keep the dataframe formatting? I know the regex pattern would be r"\b[^y]\w+\b"

Expected output:

```
         Word    Rating
    0    Bear    1
    2    Girl    3
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `startswith`

```
In [1187]: df[~df.Word.str.startswith('Y')]
Out[1187]:
   Word  Rating
0  Bear       1
2  Girl       3
```

Or, regex `match`

```
In [1203]: df[df.Word.str.match('^[^Y]')]
Out[1203]:
   Word  Rating
0  Bear       1
2  Girl       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not necessary. Just check the first letter:

```
df[df.Word.str[0] != 'Y']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lower` and `startswith` to get both uppercase 'Y' and lowercase 'y':

```
df[~df.Word.str.lower().str.startswith('y')]
```

Input:

```
df

     Word  Rating
0    Bear       1
1    Yuck       2
2    Girl       3
3  Yellow       4
4     yes       5
5   color       6
```

Output:

```
    Word  Rating
0   Bear       1
2   Girl       3
5  color       6
```